# Azure AD - AWS SSO setup via python / powershell?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, azure-active-directory

Is there anyway in which you can setup and configure Azure AD to AWS Saml via python or powershell? I have looked into it and can't quite seem to find an answer.

Comment: There is a way. Everything in Azure can be done via API. Are you asking if a script already exists? ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I haven't had any luck finding any samples or documentation

Comment: You need to create an AD identity, give that identity the necessary permissions, store your SAML in vault and then authenticate. Something like that. This can certainly be scripted, but you aren't going to find a walk through. You need to break this up and research each step independently. It also depends on what you are doing with the access.

Answer (score -1):

We have used the aws-azure-login CLI utility with great success. It works well with multi factor authentication.

https://github.com/dtjohnson/aws-azure-login